# How to provide Command-Property for custom control in MVVM (.NET MAUI)

Tags: c#, .net, mvvm, maui

I'm trying to build a custom control in .NET MAUI, that should provide an BindableProperty of ICommand for its parent. Here is a basic example for what i try to achieve.

**MainPage View (MainPage.xaml)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:views="clr-namespace:SampleApp.Views"
             x:Class="SampleApp.MainPage">

    <views:MyCustomControl DoSomething="{Binding DoSomethingCommand}"></views:MyCustomControl>
</ContentPage>
```

**MainPage View Class (MainPage.xaml.cs)**

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = new MainPageViewModel();
    }
}
```

**MainPage View Model (MainPageViewModel.cs)**

```
public class MainPageViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    public ICommand ProcessNewScoreCommand { get; }

    public MainPageViewModel()
    {
        ProcessNewScoreCommand = new Command(DoSomething);
    }

    private void DoSomething()
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

**MyCustomControl View Class (MyCustomControl.xaml.cs)**

```
public partial class MyCustomControl : ContentView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty DoSomethingProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(DoSomething), typeof(ICommand), typeof(MyCustomControl));

    public ICommand DoSomething
    {
        get => (ICommand)GetValue(DoSomethingProperty);
        set => SetValue(DoSomethingProperty, value);
    }

    public MyCustomControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = new MyCustomControlViewModel(DoSomething);
    }
}
```

**MyCustomControl View-Model (MyCustomControlViewModel.cs)**

```
public class MyCustomControlViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    public ICommand DoSomething { get; }

    public MyCustomControlViewModel(ICommand doSomethingCommand)
    {
        DoSomething = doSomethingCommand;
    }

    private void PerformSomeLogic()
    {
        // Any calulations/logic
        // ...

        if (DoSomething.CanExecute(null))
        {
            // Execute command, so that parent component gets informed and can act.
            DoSomething.Execute(null);
        }
    }
}
```

While debugging, the Property `DoSomething` of class `MyCustomControl.xaml.cs` is always null. Also it seems, that its setter isn't called at any time. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason it's not working is that you are creating a VM for your custom control i.e. the view then assigning it a context and then later on in your custom control you are changing its BindingContext all over again, Custom Controls should not have their own predefined BindingContext.

Steps to fix this:

- Remove your `MyCustomControlViewModel` class.
- Now your CustomControl.xaml.cs would look like this:

  ```
  public partial class MyCustomControl : ContentView
  {

    public static readonly BindableProperty DoSomethingProperty =
                  BindableProperty.Create(nameof(DoSomething), typeof(ICommand), typeof(MyCustomControl));

    public ICommand DoSomething
    {
        get => (ICommand)GetValue(DoSomethingProperty);
        set => SetValue(DoSomethingProperty, value);
    }

    public MyCustomControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
  }
  ```
- Now your View's VM should be the one that handles the logic so you don't have multiple BindingContext's confusing and the compiler(By searching it in the wrong place):

  public class MainPageViewModel : ObservableObject
  {

  ```
    public ICommand DoSomething { get; }

   public MainPageViewModel()
   {
      DoSomething = new Command(DoSomething);
   }
  ```

Good luck, let me know if there is some other questions you have.

A basic guide to MVVM with XF and MAUI: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-bindings-to-mvvm

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Does this mean my custom control should not receive an ViewModel at all? I'm pretty new to MVVM but this sounds like i wouldn't have any separation at all. The properties i want to define for the custom control are not relevant for the MainPage, only for visualization of the control. I want to report back a value calculated by the control based on some user input to the MainPage using the a command like mentioned in the question. Also i don't understand, how the bounded command of MainPage is triggered from the custom control (without having an own viewmodel).

Comment: In that case, your custom control is the place that should be holding your properties, more like this: https://github.com/trailheadtechnology/xf-custom-controls/blob/main/CustomControlsSample/CustomControlsSample/CustomDateTimePicker.xaml.cs, Controls don't have their separate VM, you will have a single VM that will handle all of your Views background logic

Comment: Thanks @FreakyAli, will do it like mentioned in link using codebehind. Will mark your first post as the answer, because the overall message for me should be, that custom controls have no own viewmodel. There ist only one.